# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}$ using $\varepsilon-N$ language

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

> Use an $\varepsilon-N$ argument to find and prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}$. Try some variations of your own.

I think that the limit is $1$, since the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of the $n$-th root of a polynomial(in this case it is $5+n^2$) is $1$

Comment: use binomial expansion and bernoulli's inequality

Comment: The limit is indeed $1$, and the fact you're quoting is correct; however, it sounds like you are being asked essentially to prove (using an $\varepsilon$–$N$ argument) the fact you're quoting.

Comment: You usually can't "find" a limit using $\varepsilon-N$ argument. You find a number or $\infty$ intuitively, maybe graphically or using theorems and then prove that this is the limit using a $\varepsilon-N$ argument

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}-1$ and then, for $n\ge3$,
$$ 2n^2\ge5+n^2=(a_n+1)^n\ge \binom{n}{3}a_n^3. $$
So
$$ 0\le a_n\le \sqrt[3]{\frac{12n^2}{n(n-1)(n-2)}}\le3\sqrt[3]\frac{1}{n-2}. $$
For $\forall\epsilon>0$, define
$$ N=3+\bigg[\frac{3}{\epsilon}\bigg]^3 $$
and then, if $n\ge N$,
$$ 0\le a_n<\epsilon $$
or
$$ |\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}-1|<\epsilon. $$

Comment: so how can we show explicitly that the limit is 1?

Comment: @cbcbc It is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}=s_n$ now solve the limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}log(s_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{log(5+n^2)}{n}=0$=>$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}=1$;
The step 2: fix $\epsilon_0>0$, we must show $0<\sqrt[n]{5+n^2}<\epsilon_0+1$  we know that the equation:$$log(\epsilon_0)=\frac{log(5+x^2)}{x}\hspace{0.5cm}(*)$$ have a solution in $\mathbb R^* $ for all $\epsilon_0$. Let the solution be $x(\epsilon_0)$. Then, because equation $(*)$ is equivalent with equation $(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\epsilon_0$ and function $f(x)=(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ decreases, we obtain: for all $n>=[x(\epsilon_0)]+1$ we have $(5+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}<\epsilon_0<\ \epsilon_0+1$. 
 where:$\hspace{0.5cm}[x(\epsilon_0)]$ is integer part of $x(\epsilon_0)$

Comment: how can we show explicitly that the limit is 1?

Comment: because $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{log(5+x^2)}{x}=0$ why? well... using L'hospital rule we obtain $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{log(5+x^2)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2x}{5+x^2}=0$ and because functions are continous  the limit will be the same for $n\in \mathbb N$ with $n\rightarrow\infty$